# What would be the xpath for this xml

Tags: xml, xpath

Hi I'm trying to get a variable value (ref within contractRef) in the xml below, but when I use what I assume to be the xpath:

```
/discovery/contractRef[@xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/']/@ref
```

it returns nothing. How can I get this variable, what am I missing? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<discovery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/">
  <contractRef ref="http://127.0.0.1/Services/Core/Calendar/LBCalendar.svc?wsdl" docRef="http://127.0.0.1/Services/Core/Calendar/LBCalendar.svc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/" />
</discovery>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a FAQ. The element `<discovery>` is in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/` and the child element `<contractRef>` is in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/` You need to register these namespaces with some prefix and then use those prefixes in your XPath expression. How "registering" is done, depends on the language/environment where the XPath expression is used. If the XPath is used inside an XML document, then prefixes are "registered" just by declaring a prefixed namespace, for example `xmlns:scl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/"`

Let's assume that `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/` is registered to prefix `d` and `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/` is registered to prefix `scl` then a correct XPath expression would be

```
/d:discovery/scl:contractRef/@ref
```

Namespaces are a fundamental feature in XML and XPath. Please take time to learn them. A hack to avoid using namespace prefixes in XPath expressions is to use `local-name()` function

```
/*[local-name() = 'discovery*]/*[local-name() = 'contractRef']/@ref
```

Note that the attribute name doesn't need a namespace prefix since it belongs to no-namespace.

Comment: +1 Good answer. A minor: from question it looks like @Martin is trying to test for an `xmlns` attribute. It must point out that namespace declaration are not attributes, acording to XDM and XML Infoset, in scope namespaces are accessed by a different accessor.

Answer (score 0):

I actually uploaded your xml to http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm and it I think your xpath is working.

Comment: It's not working, that is why I posted a question. Thanks for checking though.